# Como comparar números usando PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho `$valores = [0,1,3,4,5,30]` e queria verificar se existe o número `30`.

Atualmente uso `strpos()`

mas ele verifica também o `0` e o `3` e eu queria somente o `30`.

Já tentei separar por virgulas, por aspas, não funciona.

Tem alguma outra forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você tem `$valores = [0,1,3,4,5,30]`, você tem um array, você pode usar o [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$valores = [0,1,3,4,5,30];

$temTrinta = in_array(30, $valores, true);

if ($temTrinta) {
   echo "Tem o valor 30 no array";
}
```

Você também pode usar o `for` ou `foreach` e utilizar um `if` dentro, comparando cada item com o valor desejado.